# SQL templating engine to mix SQL with dynamic language? (similar to Ruby's erb)

Tags: python, sql, ruby-on-rails, templates, erb

Has anyone comes across a SQL templating engine which allows one to mix SQL with a dynamic language like Ruby or Python?

I'm looking for something similar to Ruby erb templates. For example, in Ruby on Rails you can have various templates for a view:

customers.html.erb (html + ruby)
customers.js.erb (javascript + ruby)

Though I want something like:

customers.sql.erb

The output could be a text string result of the ad-hoc SQL mixed with Ruby code.  Or even, if it's Python-based that's fine too.

Comment: Would be interesting to know why you want to do this...

Comment: Existing system already had these complex SQL queries. Wanted to re-use them to save time. Quickest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out that Ruby's erb works just fine for a SQL template. I was able to use it very easily in my Rails 3 project.

I also found that Python has a templating engine, Cheetah, which can do the same thing.

**References**

- An Introduction to ERB Templating

  - [Class: ERB (RDoc Documentation)](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/ERB.html)
- Cheetah - The Python-Powered Template Engine

  - Using Cheetah templates to make multiples outputs